# Difference Between Class with constructor and Class without when calling a function?

Tags: php, web

What's the difference between a class with constructor and class without when calling a function in this code? below is my example code

Class w/ Constructor:

```
    class DatabaseConnection
{
    public $database_host = "";
    public $database_name = "";
    public $database_username = "";
    public $database_password = "";

    public function __construct( $database_host, $database_name, $database_username, $database_password )
    {
        $this->$database_host = $database_host;
        $this->$database_name  = $database_name;
        $this->$database_username = $database_username;
        $this->$database_password  = $database_password;
    }

    public function connect_database()
    {
        $database_connection = null;

        try {
            $database_connection = new PDO( "mysql:host={$database_host};
                                            dbname={$database_name}",
                                            $database_username,
                                            $database_password );

            $database_connection->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,
                                                PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        } catch ( PDOException $pdo_exception ) {
            trigger_error( $pdo_exception,
                           E_USER_ERROR );
        }

        return $database_connection;
    }
}
```

Class without constructor:

```
    class DatabaseConnection
{
    public function connect_database( $database_host, $database_name, $database_username, $database_password )
    {
        $database_connection = null;

        try {
            $database_connection = new PDO( "mysql:host={$database_host};
                                            dbname={$database_name}",
                                            $database_username,
                                            $database_password );

            $database_connection->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,
                                                PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        } catch ( PDOException $pdo_exception ) {
            trigger_error( $pdo_exception,
                           E_USER_ERROR );
        }

        return $database_connection;
    }
}
```

Call a function in a class that has constructor:

```
$db = new DatabaseConnection( "localhost", "dbname", "username", "password" )

$db->connect_database();
```

Call a fucntion in a class that has no constructor:

```
$db = new DatabaseConnection();

$db->connect_database( "localhost", "dbname", "username", "password" );
```

Comment: If the class has a construct said construct will execute as soon as the class in initialized. That's about it.

Comment: The only difference is when you pass your connection data, in the class with the constructor you'll pass it to the constructor, in the other case you're passing it directly to the method.

Comment: but there are no difference between those codes right? it is just that the class with constructor can call any object or anything before calling any function right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically, almost everything that is done in a constructor could also be done within other functions. There are advantages in using constructors though. One huge benefit I think lies within the semantics.

### semantics of a constructor

When I say something like `$house = new House()`, I do expect to have a house. I would not expect to have a skeleton of a house, with all the walls and the roof missing. I would not expect, that I'm required to call `$house->build()` or `$house->complete()` after I created it. Because if I need to call that, it wasn't a house, it was a template of a house or a design or whatever.

The same logic goes for your `DatabaseConnection`. If I have to call `connect_database()` (in either of your two cases), I would argue, that the `DatabaseConnection` wasn't a database connection before, so what does `new DatabaseConnection([args])` actually mean in your case? It creates an object of the class `DatabaseConnection`, that can - **after creation** - be used to create a database connection. So, technically, it's a `DatabaseConnector`.

Constructors have many advantages, mainly when you don't have any influence on which functions get called on it. Let's for example assume, that you're writing a database connector for a function called `getBlogEntry`, because your blog is super dynamic and stuff.

```
var $connectionString = "mysql:localhost;someparams";

function getBlogEntry($request) {
    global $connectionString; // global is bad, but space is precious
    $db = new DatabaseConnection($connectionString);
    $db->query([query to fetch the current blog entry])
}
```

The point here is, you don't want to call a different `connect` function after creating the object. When the object exists, the connection should exist. Your API should be as clear as possible. Technically there might be no difference between doing the work in the constructor or in another function, but there sure as hell is a semantic difference. You should have a good argument not doing something in a constructor that's necessary to actually use all the functions of an object.

### answer to the question

To actually answer your question. The class with constructor has 4 member variables, which you can be sure that whoever created an object of that class has provided those values. Setting those values can of course also be done by your `connect_database`. For the `connect_database` it doesn't make a big difference if it uses member vars or params (there is of course a small difference, accessing member vars is different than params, but that should not be your concern - especially in  this case).

**However**, in your specific code example, you wouldn't need the `DatabaseConnection` class at all! You could just define the (second) function and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not required to explicitly define a constructor; however, all classes must have a constructor, and a default empty constructor will be generated if you don't provide any. If you create constructor with parameters it simply passes them to the fields in the class.

Comment: it only passes the parameters if you tell it to, its not automatic, which I think is what you meant, but wasnt very clear.

Comment: Constructor is created automatically if you don't define it because it is required. It doesn't pass any parameters if it is created automatically.

Comment: yes I know, but your answer doesnt clearly say that.